# If Active Cell Value = Offset Cell Value Then

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am trying to use Offset in Excel VBA to determine whether 2 cells are the same value.  The script is rejecting the Offset saying "Sub or Function not defined"

I have searched extensively across a number of Forums without success

```
Dim b As Integer
Dim detail As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wbk = Workbooks("Commission Statements.xlsm")
With Workbooks("Commission Statements.xlsm").Sheets("Required Data")
b = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(b, 1))

'If A2 = A1 AND B2 = B1
'Copy cells in columns D:M
'Go to Worksheet named in column A
'Paste
If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell(Offset(-1)).Value And ActiveCell(Offset(0, 1)).Value = ActiveCell(Offset(-1, 1)).Value Then
.Range(Cells(b, 4), .Cells(b, 13)).Copy
detail = .Cells(b, 1).Value
Sheets(detail).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
End If

'If A2 = A1 BUT B2 > B1
'Go to Worksheet named in Column A
'Copy cells B8:K9
'Go to bottom line of data in column K
'Paste
'Return to Active Cell in "Required Data" Worksheet
'Copy cells in columns D:M
'Go to Worksheet named in column A
'Locate last row of data in column K and offset 1 row
'Paste
ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell(Offset(-1)).Value And ActiveCell(Offset(0, 1)).Value > ActiveCell(Offset(-1, 1)).Value Then
detail = .Cells(b, 1).Value
ws.Range("B8:K9").Copy
Range("" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ws.Activate "Required Data"
Range(Cells(b, 4), .Cells(b, 13)).Copy
detail = .Cells(b, 1).Value
Sheets(detail).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues

b = b + 1

Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Each cell value in column A has an associated Worksheet to which I need to paste.
What I am seeking is as shown indented in the code.  There are 2 possible scenarios:

- cell in A = cell (offset(-1)) AND cell in B = cell (offset(-1)

or:

- cell in A = cell (offset(-1)) AND cell in B <> cell (offset(-1)

Comment: `ActiveCell(Offset(-1))` should be `ActiveCell.Offset(-1)`

Comment: in cases like this, it can be helpful to research the method in the [MSDN articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset). Here you can double check your code against the proper syntax and learn about the arguments, etc.

Comment: Hi Scott - I knew it would be something simple!  What a stupid error!